# What is the best way to implement filters in code?

Tags: visualforce

Currenty we show all user in the vf page based on the filter name and department.

Last week one user asked to update the filter with Email. I have added the filter as text box by changing the code.

Now another user expect based on division.(Text box) filter.

What is the best option to avoid code every time ?

Comment: Ask for clear and concise requirements and do it once. Sow seriously: I think you need to make some templates  and store that in custom settings. In template it should be shown which field should be filterable, with label etc. Then on VF page on load you read that template, and draw corresponding html with inputs. On click you send some remoting request to apex with entered data into your fields, and apex do filtering. That is one of the ways how to do it

Comment: Your question is subjective which may result in different answers in different directions. Share what you have done and what is your expectation, then the community will be in a better position to help or guide you.